# How to wait for any socket to have data?

Tags: python, sockets, polling

I'm implementing a socket-client which opens several sockets at the same time. Any socket may have data at a different time and I want to execute code when any socket has data and is readable.

I'm not sure how to implement this, I was looking at [select.select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) but it seems to wait for all the sockets to be readable.

I'd like to avoid using multiprocessing to handle data on the sockets, I would like it to be serial in reading from each socket but read when there is data available.

How do I wait for any socket to be readable?

```
# psudo code

sockets = [sock1, sock2, sock3]

while True:
  if len(sockets) == 0:
    break
  for sock in sockets:
    if sock.has_data():
      do_stuff(sock)
      sockets.remove(sock)
  sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: `select` does not wait for all sockets to be readable, it returns once one of them is readable.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't forget to set the sockets non-blocking if you don't ever want to block. Every function that you use will be a status reporting function that cannot be used to predict the future. A blocking read *can* block, no matter what `select` said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select.select` for your problem:

```
sockets = [sock1, sock2, sock3]
while sockets:
    rlist, _, _ = select.select(sockets, [], [])
    for sock in rlist:
        do_stuff(sock)
        sockets.remove(sock)
```

Comment: Just don't forget to set the sockets non-blocking.

Comment: The OP wants blocking, since he removes the socket after doing stuff.

Comment: True, i do want blocking.
Also, thanks Daniel, I think I just made a mistake with my attempt I was able to implement exactly what i wanted with select! :)

Comment: Then why use `select`? If you want blocking, just call `do_stuff` on each socket.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if you do that, your sockets will be dealt with in a strict sequence. Using a selector (select, poll) even with blocking sockets, allows you to react on any of the sockets becoming in readable state

Comment: @IrmendeJong No, it doesn't. As soon as one socket blocks, you won't check any of the others. If you want to ensure a socket operation doesn't block, you must set the socket non-blocking. This is an extremely common mistake that has caused huge pain many times in the past. It's equivalent to checking if there's enough disk space and then assuming that a subsequent write won't fail. The `select` function and its analogs are instantaneous status-reporting functions that don't guarantee that a future operation will not block.

Comment: (If you think that a read hit from `select` guarantees that a future read will not block, please explain the contours of that guarantee and what standard you found it in. It cannot be done. And then I can cite specific examples where that assumption failed and caused serious bugs, such as the old Linux inetd denial of service attack. Status-reporting functions like `select` and `stat` don't give future guarantees.)

Comment: `select` will indicate a socket is readable if only one byte is available.  If you then try and read 10 bytes your read __will block__.   To avoid this you have to use non-blocking sockets and check how much you've read each time.

Comment: @kicken That's not true for most protocols. For TCP, for example, a read operation will not block if at least one byte can be read immediately, regardless of how many bytes you try to read. However, your claim that "select will indicate a socket is readable if only one byte is available" is wrong for another reason -- `select` is protocol neutral and a comment like that only makes sense for some protocols. So that *cannot* be a property of the `select` operation.

Comment: It may seem like I'm nitpicking and these edge cases almost never happen, but the fact is, they *do* happen and they do cause real bugs and problems. And if you're going to educate people about what these functions do, you should spend the time and effort to get it exactly right. These functions are specified in standards, so we don't have to wing it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Could you cite the standards? I'd like to do it right because if it only appears to work but there is a potential to block on one socket while ten others complete that would be a huge issue.

Comment: @MatUtter Just set the sockets non-blocking and you are assured that they won't block. That's what setting the sockets non-blocking does. I'm not sure what you want a citation for exactly. The claim that a read hit on `select` guarantees that a future `read` will not block is a claim not found in the standards, and it's not difficult to construct practical scenarios in which that guarantee fails. Nobody has a citation to a standard where that guarantee can be found because that guarantee is not in the standards.

Comment: @MatUtter [Here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pselect.html) is the standard that specifies what `select` does. You will notice that it's a status-reporting function, just like `stat`, that tells you about the past, not the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on POSIX, take a look at `select.poll`:

```
import socket
import select
p = select.poll()
s1 = socket.socket()
s2 = socket.socket()
# call connect on sockets here...
p.register(s1, select.POLLIN)
p.register(s2, select.POLLIN)
p.poll()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.4 or newer there is the `selectors` module in the standard library. It will use the "best" I/O multiplexing implementation that your system offers (select, poll, kqueue...) There's a simple echo server example at the end of the documentation page https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html

There's a [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selectors34) of this for older Python versions available as well.