# Stopping a client until signal from server

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am working on a network project . I want my client to wait at some points until server sends the signal. (I am using python 3.7.0 on Windows 10)

I want to define a function like this:

```
def waitfor(condition,source):
    #receive bytes from source
    #decode bytes to string
    #check for condition equals to string
        return
```

I want my function to wait until string arrives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait for any socket to have data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641686/how-to-wait-for-any-socket-to-have-data)

Comment: Hi. You probably want `select` or `poll`. Please see the above link.